# Returned records (object) from API call is too large to write to a single cell

Tags: json, excel, vba

The result of an API call - and the subsequent conversion via a Json converter - has created an object that exceeds Excel's cell limit of 32,767 char.

The last bit of code after running through the Json converter is...

```
 Set oJSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(sGetResult)
 Range("A1").Value = sGetResult
```

Since I can't assign sGetResult directly into a single cell, is there a way to trim it, or split it, or somehow break it up into manageable parts within VBA itself, and then distribute it onto the worksheet for further manipulation?

I should mention that the Json converter was not written by me, as it exceeds my skill level. I could certainly edit it with guidance, but otherwise it's beyond my understanding.

Comment: Try using something like `Range("A1").Value = Left$(sGetResult,32765)`. That will give you the first 32,765 characters. Then you'll have to figure out the overall length of the result `Dim resultLen As Long; resultLen = Len(sGetResult)`, and then use the `Mid$` function to pull the rest.

Comment: That would indeed seem to do the trick. Thank you!